# Variable bounds from infinity to negative infinity - Change Limits

Tags: distributions, variance

I have a variable whose values vary between $-\infty$ and $\infty$.
I'd like to change its limits from $0$ to $1$. I want to give extremely low values when the values are less than $-1$ or greater than $1$ and want to give the highest value to the value $0$.

Which distribution would be the best here, and what's the formula to do so?
And if possible, can you guide me to some good links where I can learn more about such stuff?

Comment: How can variance be "less than -1"?? Your post is unclear - please clarify the circumstances.

Comment: Do you mean that the support of the variable is $[-\infty,\infty]$ and you want to to find a transformation such that the resulting variable has bounded support?

Comment: sorry about that. edited the post

Comment: There are an infinite number of transformations meeting your requirements - e.g. $g(z) = 1-F_{\chi^2}(z^2)$, where $F_{\chi^2}(\cdot)$ is the chi-squared cumulative distribution function - what do you mean by best? Best for what?

Answer (score 1):

I thought a few minutes about this problem, and got a feeling that it is not so easy to find nice function class which is able to (i) change its width, (ii) is normalized, and (iii) and takes the value $1$ at $x=0$.

If you can live without the third point, you can for example use a Gaussian,

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{\sigma^2}}$$

a Lorentzian,

$$f(x) = \frac{\sigma}{\sigma^2 + x^2}$$

and many more. Essentially you can use any unimodal density peaked at $x=0$.

**EDIT:** Sorry, I got the question wrong as you haven't explicitly asked for the third point. It's functional, though, so I'll leave it like this.